# How to change URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way how to change URL in browsers address bar.
For example user writes
"www.domain.com/somepage";
and I want to that user only see this:
"www.domain.com"

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iframe, frameset or ajax loading page. However, all of them are bad for SEO.

The good one to use is .htaccess URL rewrite, and set write www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/somepage

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use HTML frames, its not elegant, but with the vagueness of your question and tagging this may work for you.

Comment: No. You should never use frames for this. There are always better ways, no matter how vague a question is.

Comment: There are a few downsides to using frames in this case, search engine ranking, user experience (especially screen readers). I'm sorry you haven't had any other alternatives, and I understand if you don't accept my answer!